# SQL Virtual Column in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Is there a way to create the equivalent of a SQL virtual/computed column in a linq query within C# dotnetcore MVC page using Razor Pages and Entity Framework...

```
SELECT 0 as 'sortField'
FROM
    database
WHERE
    foo = bar
```

...but using method syntax, formed like so?:

```
Foo = await
(
    _context.Foo
        .Where(r => !StatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status))
        .Where(r => (Convert.ToDateTime(r.Statusdate) - today).TotalDays < 31)
        .Where(r => r.DSRPID == PID)
        .OrderBy(r => r.Submitteddate)
        .ThenBy(r => r.Statusdate)
        .ThenBy(r => r.recordnum)
)
.Union
(
_context.Foo
    .Where(r => !DraftStatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status))
    .Where(r => r.DSRPID == PID)
    .Where(r => r.csstatus != "not needed" || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.csstatus))
    .Where(r => !_context.Foo
                .Where(rr => rr.DSRPID == PID)
                .Select(rr => rr.Fooid)
                .Contains(r.Fooid)
          )
     .OrderBy(r => r.Submitteddate)
     .ThenBy(r => r.Statusdate)
     .ThenBy(r => r.recordnum)
)
.ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it like this:

```
class TableResults
{
  public int sortField
}

from t in context.Table select new TableResults { sortField = 0 }
```

So you would have to have a class with a property called sortField.

Comment: You can also do it with an anonymous object: `from d in database where foo == bar select new { sortField = 0 }`

Comment: True.  Depending on what you want to do with the object it can get a little dicy, so I usually create classes.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I tried to get it to work, but my query is using method syntax and I am a little new to C# so i'm not super fluent and resolving the syntax issues that I got trying to figure it out using your posts. I updated the main post to show the code that I am working with now if anyone has any further ideas!

Comment: Without a little more context of your database structure it's hard to give a better answer.   Also you may have some other issues.  If you're doing a union, you need to have the same columns selected in both queries, or at least the same type of value in each spot.

Answer (score 1):

you can use anonymous type like below in linq

```
from result in database
where foo = bar
select new { sortField=0 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried to get this to work, but my query is using method syntax and I am a little new to C# so i'm not super fluent and resolving the syntax issues that I got trying to figure it out using your post. I updated the main post to show the code that I am working with now if you have any further ideas! Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

*equivalent of a SQL virtual/computed column* will be readonly property.

You can do it in your entity class if instance will contain all required values for calculating it's value

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SortValue => Id == 42 ? 0 : Id;
}

_context.Foo.Where(f => somecondition)
            .OrderBy(f => f.SortValue)
            .ToList();
```

In case instance doesn't have all required values for calculation you can use anonymous type

```
_context.Foo.Where(f => somecondition)
            .Select(f => new
            {
                Id = f.Id,
                Name = f.Name,
                SortValue = f.Name == "External name" ? 0 : 1
            })
            .OrderBy(f => f.SortValue)
            .ToList();
```